# how to make checkbox behave like radio button in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-forms

I have a group of checkboxes, and also a newly added checkbox. I would like to disable the added checkbox if any of the checkboxes from the group are checked and disable the group of checkboxes if the new checkbox is checked. I tried something like this:

```html
<td *ngFor="let value of GroupRequestDesc;let $index=index " class="col-sm-6" style="padding-right: 15px;">
    <label for="checkbox_group2" class="checkbox cb_pad" style="width: 180px;display:inline-block;">
        <input id="checkbox_group2" class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" [checked]="checkbox1" value="{{value.ReqGroupId}}" [disabled]="value.ReqGroupDesc == ReqGroupDesc || ReqGroupName == 'SERVICE_ACCESS_GROUP'" (change)="checkboxVisibility(value.nxReqGroupId,$event)" /><i class="skin"></i><span>{{value.nxReqGroupDesc}}</span>
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <label for="checkbox_group3" class="checkbox cb_pad" style="width: 180px;">
        <input id="checkbox_group3" class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="" [checked]="checkbox2" [disabled]="requestGroupName =='SERVICE_ACCESS_GROUP'" /><i class="skin"></i><span>Create New Group</span>
    </label>
</td>
```

> Function to check checkbox is selected or not

```js
checkboxVisibility(value, event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        console.log('hi its checked');
        this.checkedList.push(value);
        console.log('hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh', this.checkedList);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.groupvalues.length; i++) {
            if (this.checkedList[i] == value) {
                this.checkedList.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Checkbox group and newly added checkbox should behave like radio button.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the apparance of the radio to checkbox, just insert this style:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;    /* Firefox */
  -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
}
```

Comment: Francesco M. Hi I need behaviour of checkbox to be like radio button.

Comment: Yes, then it's not better to change only the appance of the radio button as checkbox so you have the same behaviour ?

Comment: No i don't have the same behaviour. I am getting group of checkbox, and also newly added checkbox. so here condition is like if any of checkbox from group is selected i need to disable newly added checkbox and if newly added checkbox is selected other should disable.